# Howto indent properly windows batch file with logparser script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, indentation, logparser

I have a batch file with long logparser commands. I want to display/edit them in multiple lines to make them me clear/understandable.

For example content of a windows batch file:

```
logparser "SELECT id2 as SN, replace_chr(creation_date,'-','/') as creation_date , case replace_chr(last_access,'-','/') when '\N' then '' else replace_chr(last_access,'-','/') end as Last_access, sale_id,case to_int(div(to_int(sub(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP(),to_timestamp(last_access,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))),86400)) when NULL then 999 else  to_int(div(to_int(sub(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP(),to_timestamp(last_access,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))),86400)) end as nb_days_Last_update INTO 'temp logs\report.csv' FROM 'raw data\devices.csv'  WHERE (id2<>'000000000000' AND [os]='HDPVRSTB' AND strlen(to_string(id2))=12 AND TO_INT(id2) IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY id2 ASC"  -i:TSV -fixedSep:ON -iSeparator:tab -o:TSV -oSeparator:; -headers:ON -dtLines:0
```

Any idea ? problem is the mix of "" and '' ...

Comment: Put your commands into a file and execute: `logparser file:sqltext.sql`. You can then format the commands like a normal sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a circumflex to escape the line endings.

```
logparser "SELECT id2 as SN, replace_chr(creation_date,'-','/') ^
as creation_date , case replace_chr(last_access,'-','/') when '\N' ^
then '' else replace_chr(last_access,'-','/') ^
end as Last_access, sale_id,case to_int(div(to_int(sub(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP(),to_timestamp(last_access,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))),86400)) ^
when NULL then 999 else  to_int(div(to_int(sub(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP(),to_timestamp(last_access,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))),86400)) end ^
as nb_days_Last_update INTO 'temp logs\report.csv' FROM 'raw data\devices.csv'  ^
WHERE (id2<>'000000000000' AND [os]='HDPVRSTB' AND strlen(to_string(id2))=12 AND TO_INT(id2) IS NOT NULL) ^
ORDER BY id2 ASC"  -i:TSV -fixedSep:ON -iSeparator:tab -o:TSV -oSeparator:; -headers:ON -dtLines:0
```